# Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors

Tags: ssd, smart

I have received 3 emails this month from my system that contains this error:

```
Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
```

But when running smartctl I see no evidence that anything is wrong, the raw read error rate is 0.  Why am I getting these errors?

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       6161
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       67
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   096   096   000    Old_age   Always       -       66
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       41
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   065   035   000    Old_age   Always       -       35 (Min/Max 0/65)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain 0x0030   096   096   001    Old_age   Offline      -       4
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Total_Host_Sector_Write 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12434743090
247 Host_Program_Page_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       219482532
248 FTL_Program_Page_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       500545158

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged
```

Output of grep -i sdf /var/log/syslog*

```
/var/log/syslog.1:Jun 26 05:21:44 home smartd[1215]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], 1 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
/var/log/syslog.1:Jun 26 05:21:44 home smartd[1215]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], SMART Usage Attribute: 194 Temperature_Celsius changed from 70 to 65
/var/log/syslog.1:Jun 26 05:51:45 home smartd[1215]: Device: /dev/sdf [SAT], No more Currently unreadable (pending) sectors, warning condition reset after 1 email
```

Comment: Is this a HDD or SSD? If you `grep -i sdf /var/log/syslog*` what do you see?

Comment: @heynnema aside from temperature messages and the emailed message, just `No more Currently unreadable (pending) sectors, warning condition reset after 1 email`

Comment: I'd just keep an eye on it then. Why is the disk running a little hot? Is this a Seagate drive?

Comment: @heynnema It's an Crucial SSD.  I don't know why it is showing that high.  smartctl says it is only 36C, but the logs report hourly temps above 64C.  In fact there are 10 disks, the logs report most of them running high when live checks are <41C, one as high as 120C, but when I check that live, its only 37C.

Comment: It sounds like this must be a desktop machine, yes? I'd check the fans and the air flow for possible dead spots, or bad fans.

Comment: @heynnema As per https://serverfault.com/questions/693163/is-smartd-really-reporting-this-drive-is-too-hot the value in the logs is the 'VALUE' column, not the actual Celcius temperature shown in 'RAW_VALUE'.

Comment: Good info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up upgrading to a Samsung 1TB and the issue went away.  I assume it was hardware related.